# Why, when one memory subset of a string is passed to a int variable, does printing give me a completely different value?

Tags: c++

I want the first character in string example1 to print out. Using example1[0] seems to work, but for some reason having an int variable have that same value will output 49. Why does this happen, and how can I make the LOG(print) print 1 instead of 49?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define LOG(x) std::cout<<x<<std::endl;
int main() {
    std::string example1 = {"1 2 3 4 5"};
    int print = 0;
    LOG(example1[0]);
    //this prints 1
    print = example1[0];
    LOG(print)
    //this, somehow, prints 49. Why?
}
```

Comment: Try `char print = 0;` instead. Types matter and `char` is not the same as `int`.

Comment: For more fun: `LOG(example1[0]) LOG(example1[2]) LOG(example1[0] + example1[2])`

Answer (score 2):

When you write `example1[0]`, that's a `char`; if you convert it to an `int`, it's the ASCII value of it (or, in older/different systems, the value in the specific character table).

Comment: Which is to say, both lines using the `LOG` macro actually send 49 (assuming ASCII) to the output, but one sends 49 as a character value (resulting in the character that looks like `1`) and the other sends 49 formatted as an integer value (resulting in multiple characters: `4` for the tens place, `9` for the ones place)

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! This makes total sense now, and looking more into ascii myself, I discovered how to convert int values into asci and indeed 1 is "represented" as 49 in Ascii